# how to go through your database multiple times in a while loop?

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

i'm working on an webshop and when i add 2 books of the same author i get an error.
i think it's because of the fetch. any idea how to fix this?

[image]

```
require_once '../connect.php';


$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `product` ");
$query->execute();
$product = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$query2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `auteur`");
$query2->execute();
$auteur = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

```
    while ($product ) {
        $id = $product['productID'];
        echo "<div class='card'>";
        echo "<p><button class='wishlist' onclick= 'window.location.href= `wishlist.php`'><i class='fa-sharp fa-solid fa-heart'></i></button></p>";
        echo "<img src='../fotos/$id.jpg' alt='geen foto'>";
        echo "<div class='container'>";
        echo "<h1>". $product['naam'] . "</h1>";
        echo "<p class='price'>" .'€ ' . $product['prijs'] . "</p>";
        if ($product['AuteurID'] == $auteur['AuteurID']){
            echo "<p class='auteur'>".$auteur['Naam'] ."</p>";
        }
        
        echo "<div class='prod_buy'>";
        echo "<p><button onclick= 'window.location.href= `product_page.php?id=$id`'>meer info</button></p>";
        echo "<p><button class='buy' onclick= 'window.location.href= `wishlist.php`'><i class='fa-sharp fa-solid fa-cart-plus'></i></button></p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        $product = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $auteur = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Comment: So as you are not showing us 41 lines of code, which one is line 41

Comment: if ($product['AuteurID'] == $auteur['AuteurID']){

Comment: So probably you have a `$product` but not an `$auteur`

Comment: You have told us NOTHING about how you create either of those 2 arrays! So we are not going to be able to say anythng more than you have a problem

Comment: @RobEyre i have one but not here in the code i showed

Comment: Basically, one of the FETCH commands has run out of rows and returned FALSE (a bool), probably `$auteur` as you test for the other in the while loop So `while ($product && $auteur)` may be your dirty solution

Comment: This situation could be ocurring if `$query` has more records than `$query2`

Comment: Those 2 tables should be joined somhow, that means you could get this result with ONE sensible query with a JOIN

Comment: @RiggsFolly sadly it isn't the solution because then he doesn't shows the second book of the author

Comment: WHat is not the solution.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry didn't see the second reply you did. but the solution with the joining of tables worked. thanks!